# Any way in statsmodels to obtain final observations used in a regression?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Very frequently, regressions will drop some observations because they are missing one or more regressor fields. For example:

```
In [30]: len(df)  #df is our dataframe
Out[30]: 39243

In [31]: model = sm.OLS(df[var_name_y], df[var_names_x], missing="drop")
         result = model.fit()

In [32]: len(result.fittedvalues)
Out[32]: 38013
```

Here, we dropped 1230 observations, each of which was missing one or more regressors.

Is there any way to get access to the `DataFrame` that was actually used in the regrssion - that is, the smaller one of size 38013 that remains after the regression dropped the missing observations? This is available, for example, in the various SAS regression routines. I have been combing the API but am unable to locate anything. I need this data to produce various diagnostics based on the actual data used in the regression.

Of course, I could drop the correct rows myself before the regression, like this:

```
In [58]: len(df)
Out[58]: 39243

In [59]: df2 = df.dropna(subset=var_name_y + var_names_x)
In [60]: len(df2)
Out[60]: 38013

In [64]: model = sm.OLS(df2[var_name_y], df2[var_names_x],missing="drop")
         result = model.fit()
In [65]: len(result.fittedvalues)
Out[65]: 38013
```

Then the `DataFrame` that I feed to the regression is already the one with all the missing observations removed. But I was hoping to avoid that, particularly if I am working with a much larger dataset. Is there a better way to do this, particularly programmatically accessing the post-regression `DataFrame` via the `OLS` model class or the `RegressionResultsWrapper` output of the fit?

Comment: I don't really understand the last part and how this relates to larger datasets. We always have to create a new array or dataframe, whether the user does it or statsmodels does it. The numpy array that was used in OLS regression, or in any other model, is available as `model.exog`. I'm not sure where the information about the dataframe index is attached, and it might be for internal use only, i.e. no established API for it.

Comment: `dir(model.data)` will show the information about the initial data handling. But since it wasn't intended as public, I wouldn't rely on a stable API for it.

Comment: a comment to you your code for dropping na. it's better to keep the response variable y in the same dataset while dropping observations in case there are also missing values in y. When we want to compare models, then it is better to drop missing values for all variables, so we have a common dataset for the estimation of different models, which means that the user has to do it.

Comment: +1 on all of these.  Argh I can't believe I forgot the regressand!  Thanks for catching that.  Will fix either tonight or tomorrow AM.  Will also try the internal API method you showed.

Comment: Using `model.endog` and `model.exog` for the data, and then `model.endog_names` and `model.exog_names` to make the column index, I can reconstruct the data used in the regression.  Thank you for pointing me in this direction!  I suggest you post this in answer format so I can upvote and accept it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest approach to get what you ask seems to rely on `model.data`, as suggested by user333700 in the comments. Differently from what user333700 states, then, `model.data` [seems to have deliberately exposed as public interface](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/402/) by statsmodels developers.

In particular, `model.data.missing_row_idx` provides what you ask [since 2012](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/commit/0ce2f66279bd559cca082a3de24779b99b35ad25#diff-2e18ce91dae3e3e78a23ba177fdfce58R56)... so although undocumented, it seems relatively stable.

Example:

```
In [3]: model = OLS(pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, float('nan')]]), [2, 5, 4], missing='drop')

In [4]: model.data.missing_row_idx
Out[4]: [2]
```